# Virgola alla fine di una lista di esempi di possibili soggetti - ci vuole o no?

Tags: punctuation, list

Questa frase mi sembra abbastanza corretta:

> Giochi difficili (come scacchi, go, e bridge) sfoggiano regole che...

Ma se volessi togliere le parentesi? Dove metterei le virgole?

> Giochi difficili come scacchi, go, e bridge sfoggiano regole che...
>
> Giochi difficili come scacchi, go, e bridge, sfoggiano regole che...
>
> Giochi difficili, come scacchi, go, e bridge, sfoggiano regole che...

Answer (score 5):

La seconda versione sicuramente è sconsigliabile: di fatto si sta mettendo una virgola tra il soggetto e il verbo (“Gianni, mangia una mela”). La prima e la terza vanno bene, quanto alla questione della domanda.

Personalmente, però, limerei un altro po' di cose:

- L'uso di “[sfoggiare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sfoggiare)” in questa frase è strano: significa “ostentare, esibire con compiacimento”, che suona un po' strano detto di giochi e delle loro regole.
- La virgola prima della “e” che precede l'ultimo termine di un elenco non si usa in italiano (a differenza dell'inglese).
- Infine (ma questo è più soggettivo), prima dei nomi dei giochi mi suonano meglio gli articoli.

In definitiva, io scriverei qualcosa come: “Giochi difficili [o forse ‘complessi’] come gli scacchi, il go e il bridge hanno regole che...”.

Comment: Fra l'altro, la cosiddetta [“Oxford comma”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) è dibattuta. A quanto pare “The Times” raccomanda ai suoi autori di non usarla.

Comment: @egreg, è dibattuta in inglese o anche in italiano? A me piace, e mi convincono anche le motivazioni a supporto del suo uso.

Comment: @Enlico Dibattuta nell'ambito dell'inglese. A me non piace affatto.

Comment: @Enlico: In italiano non si usa proprio; in inglese, come dice egreg, qualcuno la raccomanda, qualcuno la sconsiglia. (Ah, oops, doppione con egreg: scrivo dal telefono.)